# Lucene: Search for documents that dont have specific field

Tags: java, lucene, booleanquery

I need to select all documents that dont have specific field, and have right value for one field. I am trying to avoid using "null" string as value for fields that are null, so by lucene, those fields are not saved for those documents.

Document structure looks like this

```
class familyMember {
   String id;
   String name;
   String parentId; // Id of familyMember object which is parent of this member
}
```

What I want, is to get all the familyMembers that do not have a parent. So lets say the root of the tree, if you look at it like that.

I tried many ways but this one looks like best way:

```
if (parentId != null) {
    Query parentIdQuery = new TermQuery(new Term("parentID", parentId.toString()));
    booleanQuery.add(parentIdQuery, BooleanClause.Occur.MUST);
} else {
    QueryParser queryParser = new QueryParser(LUCENE_VERSION, "parentId"), analyzer);
    queryParser.setAllowLeadingWildcard(true);
    Query parentIdQuery = queryParser.parse("%%");
    booleanQuery.add(parentIdQuery, BooleanClause.Occur.MUST_NOT);
}
```

But for some reason, every time I try this query, I get all familyMambers that don't have a parent except one! And whatever tree structure I try at the end I finish with only **ONE** member that has a parent....

Does someone know what I am doing wrong or knows better way for finding documents that don't have one field?

I am using booleanQuery because after this I have checking if user wants to more conditions, like get me all members that don't have a parent and has name like "Bill".

EDIT 1:
I've tried this one too, but again same problem.

```
if (parentId != null) {
    Query parentIdQuery = new TermQuery(new Term("parentID", parentId.toString()));
    booleanQuery.add(parentIdQuery, BooleanClause.Occur.MUST);
} else {
    Query parentIdQuery = new TermQuery(new Term("parentID", "%%"));
    booleanQuery.add(parentIdQuery, BooleanClause.Occur.MUST_NOT);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, i found solution. Trick was in

```
new ConstantScoreQuery(new FieldValueFilter());
```

Solution:

```
if (parentId != null) {
    Query parentIdQuery = new TermQuery(new Term("parentID", parentId.toString()));
    booleanQuery.add(parentIdQuery, BooleanClause.Occur.MUST);
} else {
    Query parentIdQuery = new ConstantScoreQuery(new FieldValueFilter("parentID", true));
    booleanQuery.add(parentIdQuery, BooleanClause.Occur.MUST);
```

}